# ПО банкомата, с стандарта XFS (eXtensions for Financial Services)

Tags: c#

Всем привет. В настоящее время я работаю над проектом ATM. Банкомат состоит из четырех основных устройств (диспенсер, монет приёмник, картридер, принтер). Насколько я знаю, для управления всеми устройство банкоматами необходимо использовать стандарт XFS. Работаю на языке программирования C#. Я нашел несколько примеров в Интернете ([здесь](https://github.com/arsene0121/XFS.Net), [и здесь](https://github.com/mortezabarzkar/XFS4NET)), но я их не понимаю. Мой вопрос: как я могу управлять все устройству (например диспенсер) банкомата, используя стандарт XFS?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Лучше честно признайтесь, что у вас недостаточная квалификация для работы над этим проектом и смените его на другой или поменяйте место работы. Это не тот случай когда можно скопипастить примеры из интернетов.

Comment: Мне надо написать программ для управление диспенсера(NCR) банкомата

Comment: На таком уровне безопасности код вы должны писать только самостоятельно. Документацию по работе с железом и необходимые библиотеки, пусть даже нативные, должен предоставить вендор устройства. У вас должно быть все необходимое для этого, я не понимаю откуда возник данный вопрос. Если у вас нет всего необходимого, отправляйте запросы вендору, добивайтесь предоставления документации и библиотек.

Comment: Ну и изучайте стандарт XFS, там написано как вы можете управлять устройствами.